# Como imprimir Relaciones con Eloquent sin el metodo "implode" y "pluck"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo relaciones `hasMany y belongsTo`, cuando intento imprimirlas obviamente accedo al modelo User de esta manera.

Tengo dos Modelos, ExperienciaLaboral y Users,

Modelo User

```
public function expLaboral()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ExperienciaLaboral::class);
}
```

y Modelo ExperienciaLaboral

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Con esto me deja acceder de esta manera

```
auth()->user()->expLaboral()->pluck('Empresa')->implode(' ');
```

Pero como un usuario puede tener mucha Experiencia Laboral al querer imprimirlo en una tabla com `implode` bueno obvio se junta todo y quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de imprimir solo toda la Experiencia Laboral sin necesidad de Implode

Comment: No termino de entender la duda, buscas obtener al usuario y todos sus registros asociados de experiencia laboral ?

Comment: es correcto, he logrado imprimir estas incidencias pero solo con el metodo implode y el metodo pluck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indicas trabajar con una relación de **1:N** entre el modelo de `User` y el modelo de `ExperienciaLaboral`, por lo tanto deberías corregir lo siguiente:

- En el modelo `User` debes tener un método llamado `expLaborales()` de este modo:

Código

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function expLaborales()
    {
         return $this->hasMany(ExperienciaLaboral::class);
    }
}
```

- Ahora en el modelo `ExperienciaLaboral` un método llamado `user()` así:

Código

```
class ExperienciaLaboral extends Model 
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Lo que hice fué:

- El método se llamará `expLaborales()` debido a que estamos indicando que un usuario tiene muchos registros de experiencia laboral, entonces esto debe ir en plural.
- El método se llamará `user()` en el modelo `ExperienciaLaboral` debido a que aquí indicamos que varias experiencias laborales pertenecen a un usuario.

Posterior....

Ahora en un controlador que asumamos se llama: `UserController.php` hacemos la consulta así:

```
$datos = User::with('expLaborales')->get();
```

Lo que hice fué:

- Con `eager loading` cargo todas las relaciones del modelo `User` con el modelo `ExperienciaLaboral` a través del método `expLaborales()` recién creado

Lo siguiente que hago es en la vista iterar la colección que la consulta anterior me esta devolviendo de este modo:

```
@foreach($datos as $data)
    {{ $data->name }}
    @foreach($data->expLaborales as $expLaboral)
        {{ $expLaboral->nombreExperienciaLaboral }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

- El primer `foreach()` lo usamos para recorrer los datos del modelo `User` que nos ha retornado la consulta
- El segundo `foreach` lo usamos para recorrer los datos que nos ha retornado el método `expLaborales()` que esta vinculado con el modelo `ExperienciaLaboral`
- Para recuperar el nombre de la columna donde esta el nombre de la experiencia laboral, solo debes modificar esta línea:

Código

```
{{ $expLaboral->nombreExperienciaLaboral }}
```

solo cambia **`nombreExperienciaLaboral`** por el nombre de la columna correspondiente.

> Importante: Para trabajar con las relaciones que ofrece Laravel, debes hacer uso de los métodos para los cuales dispone de ello y en especial si estas trabajando con una relación de **1:N** usa `eager loading` para hacer una *carga ambiciosa* del modelo principal con sus registros vinculados.

**Referencias**

- [eagger loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)
- [one to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)